# Excel external workbook references- dynamic

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to solve an issue in Excel 2010 where I'm referencing external workbooks that aren't open (so INDIRECT isn't an option) and I'd like the cell reference to be dynamic.

The external cell reference works when typed like this:
`='[ABBOTT.SEAN.xlsx]2016'!$C$18`

This is fine if I only ever want that cell. However, I created a VLOOKUP on another sheet to use the TODAY function in conjunction with the pay period list to determine which row to grab. The purpose of to set it once and never have to manually change which row to select ever again.

Logically, I thought that I could reference the cell on the other sheet in place of the `$18`, nesting in in parentheses. Either inside or outside parentheses returns an error. Is there a way to reference the dynamic cell and make it work in an external closed document cell reference formula?

Comment: Don't fight with Excel........just open the workbook.

Comment: Have you tried naming the cell and using the named range in the referring formula? instead of $C$18, use CeeEighteen.